# How to skip a test in FlatSpec?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, intellij-idea, scalatest

I know that a unit test is broken:

```
it should "be true" in {
  assert(false)
}
```

Yet I don't want to fix it right now but mark it as skipped. There should be a highly visible and also very *concise* warning in the output of the test run which is why commenting the code won't suffice.

I found the `cancel` command:

```
it should "be true" in {
  cancel("skipped")
  assert(false)
}
```

and while this looks good in the console through `sbt test`:

```
[info] - should be true !!! CANCELED !!!
```

it spams the console in IntelliJ with a huge stacktrace:

```
Test Canceled: skipped


org.scalatest.exceptions.TestCanceledException: skipped
    at org.scalatest.Assertions.newTestCanceledException(Assertions.scala:531)
    at org.scalatest.Assertions.newTestCanceledException$(Assertions.scala:530)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.newTestCanceledException(FlatSpec.scala:1685)
    at org.scalatest.Assertions.cancel(Assertions.scala:1141)
    at org.scalatest.Assertions.cancel$(Assertions.scala:1137)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.cancel(FlatSpec.scala:1685)
    at com.dreamlines.metronome.entities.MarshallingTest.$anonfun$new$3(MarshallingTest.scala:108)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf$(OutcomeOf.scala:83)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1682)
    at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture(TestSuite.scala:196)
    at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture$(TestSuite.scala:195)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.withFixture(FlatSpec.scala:1685)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.invokeWithFixture$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1680)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.$anonfun$runTest$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1692)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:289)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.runTest(FlatSpecLike.scala:1692)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.runTest$(FlatSpecLike.scala:1674)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTest(FlatSpec.scala:1685)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.$anonfun$runTests$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1750)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.$anonfun$runTestsInBranch$1(Engine.scala:396)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:384)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:379)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:461)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.runTests(FlatSpecLike.scala:1750)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.runTests$(FlatSpecLike.scala:1749)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTests(FlatSpec.scala:1685)
    at org.scalatest.Suite.run(Suite.scala:1147)
    at org.scalatest.Suite.run$(Suite.scala:1129)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.org$scalatest$FlatSpecLike$$super$run(FlatSpec.scala:1685)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.$anonfun$run$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1795)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:521)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.run(FlatSpecLike.scala:1795)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.run$(FlatSpecLike.scala:1793)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.run(FlatSpec.scala:1685)
    at org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:45)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13(Runner.scala:1346)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13$adapted(Runner.scala:1340)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1340)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24(Runner.scala:1031)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24$adapted(Runner.scala:1010)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1506)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1010)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:850)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:131)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:28)
```

What else can I do if I want to skip a test and don't want to fallback to tags?

Comment: Can you not just comment out the test and add a `TODO` to remind yourself to uncomment it when it should pass?

Comment: @JamesWhiteley I could. Yet I am forgetful and I *will* forget. I have a personal policy of never commenting code blocks but it's strictly: either delete or fix the code. (If I need to restore the code I can access git history or local history.) I don't want to remind myself, I want `sbt test` to remind me that I skipped tests on every test run.

Comment: That's fair enough. I guess I'm now in the habit of checking my `TODO` tab in IntelliJ every once in a while since people kept calling me out when I tried to make pull requests without checking for commented out code. You live and you learn...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While `ignore` will work, the test is not run at all, and even when the functionality is fixed, the test might continue to be ignored. Since you've said you are worried about forgetting to turn the test back on, I'd suggest `pendingUntilFixed`. The test is still run, and if the assertions fail, the test is ignored. However, when the functionality is fixed, and the assertions pass, the test *fails*, reminding you to turn it back on. It's added after the `in`, like this:

```
it should "be true" in pendingUntilFixed {
  assert(false)
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**You can also put the `ignore` instead of `in`** - so you can also ignore the test cases with 'text'.

Here an example:

```
  "After running the code" should "be true" ignore {
    assert(???)
  }
  it should "be true in any case" ignore {
    assert(???)
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Replace the `it` keyword with [`ignore`](http://doc.scalatest.org/1.8/org/scalatest/FlatSpec.html):

```
ignore should "be true" in {
  assert(false)
}
```

It will mark the test as ignored:

```
 [info] - should be true !!! IGNORED !!!
```

and won't spam the console in IntellJ.

Furthermore, while you can use `cancel` for skipping, use it if, and only if, a pre-condition fails for your test-case. E.g. if you rely in a functional test on an external webserver and it is currently not reachable, you may not want to fail the test but cancel it.

Comment: Good tip about the uses of `cancel`.